# Update Excel document without checking in and checking out

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel, excel-services, check-out

Suppose we upload a shared Excel document in the SharePoint 2013.

If we try to edit it allows to edit for a windows user and allows to save it.

If then another windows user tries to edit the same Excel at a same time it also allows the user to edit it, but if we try to save it the document will not be updated (edited by another user).

We are not using Excel Services of SharePoint Server 2013.

Why will the Excel document not be updated without check out/in?

Are there any settings to be made?

We are not in a domain group (using `workgroup`) and do not get any kind of error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: We do not get error its just not updating the excel

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-workspace-help/resolving-conflicts-and-errors-in-sharepoint-workspace-HA010382158.aspx

Comment: It was for work group .I meant it for Directly editing excel in SP